# animation not showing

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and I have trouble with this small bit of code. I'm trying to make a little animation of a beam shooting from a rocket for a game, but the animation just doesn't show. The beam goes to the correct location but it just randomly shows up there after some lag (the delay time?). I also tried using `Thread.sleep()` instead but got the same results. My code might not be great and there are probably better methods out there to use but I just want to know what could solve my problem.

```
private static final double DELAY = 8.0; 

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    double x = shipA.getX() + shipA.getWidth()/2;
    double y = shipA.getY();
    beam = new GLine(x, y-BEAM_LENGTH, x, y-BEAM_LENGTH*2);
    add(beam);
    beamMove();
}

private void beamMove() {
    dy = 3.0; 
    while (true) {
        pause(DELAY);
        moveBeam();

        if (beam.getY() <= Y_MARGIN) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void moveBeam() {
    beam.move(0, -dy);
}
```

Comment: Might just be me but I do not see any canvas draw() calls. Are you actually drawing the beam again after each move call. If not you should.